# Need help for Decrement Number

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little questions I want decrement a number (-1) with PHP when the page is refresh.

I want when the page is refresh it's show my number in database and this Remove -1 of the number

Example: In my database FROM Number WHERE ID (I want decrement -1 when page is refresh)
So if I go on my page it's show me my number I have in ID (99878309) and when I refresh this page
the number change to -1 (99878308)

I have already this show my ID with an echo it's not work

Code I have try for show my ID

```
$this->query("SELECT skinsID FROM accounts WHERE ID COLLATE latin1_bin LIKE ?";
```

But the code no work

Comment: Basically `UPDATE x SET number=number-1 WHERE ??`.

Comment: You'll need to share more code. Your code that you shared is a SQL query to retrieve a `skinsID` from the `accounts` table where `ID` equals some unstated value. This has nothing to do with "Decrementing a number on page refresh".

Comment: As a note, "code no work" is not a sufficiently detailed diagnostic. The code you've shown doesn't even have proper syntax, it's missing a closing `)`. Is that the issue? We don't know because you need to tell us the **exact error message** you're getting.

Comment: *"But the code no work"* - Doesn't work *how?*

Comment: How can we help with if your explanation is "it's not work"???  Not work how?  Error out?  No result?  Wrong result?

Comment: Idk what code i can add on my PHP for make that (show on page my number in database + when page is refresh it's change number to -1)

Answer (score -1):

I have make a little code for add + show on my page code

So, i want now it's make -1 when page is refresh and it's show number with -1 exemple:

My number is 879987 if i refresh it's update in database my number with -1 (879986)
And on my page it's show my number updated in database with -1

My code:

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=do****i57;charset=utf8', 'downwuon_m****21', 'mo****21');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

// Add number in database
$bdd->exec('UPDATE skins SET code = 10 WHERE id = 1');

$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT code FROM skins WHERE id = 1');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
    echo $donnees['code'] . '<br />';
}

$reponse->closeCursor();

?>
```